# False Drive Partition in Windows 8 - How to Delete?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

All on a sudden my Windows explorer became slower and taking more than 5 mins(sometime 10 mins too) to open properly. But I noticed some false hard drive partitions auto created and when I click any one of them the Windows explorer going to "not responding" state.

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

These partitions are also not visible in - Manage >> Disk Management

[image: Image 3]

I am not sure how they are created and why making windows explorer slower.

I have:  - Windows 8 Pro, Intel Pentium CPU G3250 3.20 GHZ, RAM 8 GB, System Type - 64 bit

Please suggest how to delete those partitions and bring back windows explorer to previous state.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please suggest how to delete those partitions

```
net use g: /delete
net use h: /delete
```

etc.

> ```
> Disconnect from a share
>  NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE
>
> Disconnect from a share and close all resources (undocumented)
>  NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE /Y
> ```

Source [Net use - Connect to a File/Printer Share - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) - Map a drive letter to a remote server/share.